# Comparison of two dates fails (leap year influence)

Tags: javascript, date, comparison

30th January and 1st February seems to be equal on leap years.

`new Date(1972, 01, 30).getTime() == new Date(1972, 02, 01).getTime(); // true`

30th January and 2nd February seems to be equal on non-leap years.

`new Date(1973, 01, 30).getTime() == new Date(1973, 02, 02).getTime(); // true`

1st February and 2nd February seems to work every time.

`new Date(1973, 02, 01).getTime() == new Date(1973, 02, 02).getTime(); // false
new Date(1972, 02, 01).getTime() == new Date(1972, 02, 02).getTime(); // false`

Looping over 19 years: https://jsfiddle.net/rd1qe9bt/3/

**Why does it work like this and can I somehow differentiate these dates?**

Comment: Did you check `console.log(new Date(1972, 01, 30))` and `console.log(new Date(1972, 02, 01))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments to the Date() function are slightly off. The month runs from 0 - 11 for January to December.

When your examples are modified to use the proper format, they behave as expected:

```
// comparing January 30, 1972 to February 1, 1972
new Date(1972, 0, 30).getTime() == new Date(1972, 01, 01).getTime(); // false

// comparing January 30, 1973 to February 2, 1973
new Date(1973, 0, 30).getTime() == new Date(1973, 02, 02).getTime(); // false
```

The arguments for your examples comparing the 1st and 2nd of February were correct, which is why they worked every time.